# How to check request value by groovy in SoapUI

Tags: xml, groovy, request, soapui

I have simple mock service with request like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fa1="http://TargetNamespace.com/FA1">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <fa1:items>
         <fa1:itemname>logo</fa1:itemname>
         <fa1:price></fa1:price>
         <fa1:vat>10</fa1:vat>
         <fa1:description>nové logo</fa1:description>
      </fa1:items>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have used script to control response value.
At the start XmlHolder didn't work. So I used

```
def req = mockRequest.getContentElement().execQuery("/")
def records = new XmlParser(false, false).parseText(req[0].xmlText())
```

to get request and parse it into nodes.

```
{http://TargetNamespace.com/FA1}items[attributes={}; value=[
{http://TargetNamespace.com/FA1}itemname[attributes={}; value=[logo]], 
{http://TargetNamespace.com/FA1}price[attributes={}; value=[1]], 
{http://TargetNamespace.com/FA1}vat[attributes={}; value=[10]], 
{http://TargetNamespace.com/FA1}description[attributes={}; value=[nové logo]]]
]
```

But I cannot get price value. I have tried

```
def price = records.price.text()
```

Expression `records.find( { it.text() == "1"} )` returns `{http://TargetNamespace.com/FA1}price[attributes={}; value=[1]]`
but `records.find( { it.name() == "price"} )` alike `records.find( { it.name() == "{http://TargetNamespace.com/FA1}price"} )` returns null.

Comment: That should be `<fa1:price>1</fa1:price>`

Comment: Not should but can. I test price for null/not null value.

Answer (score 0):

The key is use
`def records = new XmlParser(`**false, false**`).parseText(req[0].xmlText())`

That brings request value like this:

```
fa1:items[attributes={xmlns:soapenv=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/, xmlns:fa1=http://TargetNamespace.com/FA1}; value=[
fa1:itemname[attributes={}; value=[logo]], 
fa1:price[attributes={}; value=[1]], 
fa1:vat[attributes={}; value=[10]], 
fa1:description[attributes={}; value=[nové logo]]]
]
```

Then you can read value by name `namespace:name` so
`records.find( { it.name() == "fa1:price"} ).text()` returns **1**

Comment: Why is the key to use the same flags as in the question? You can also access the tag directory without the find: `records."soapenv:Body"."fa1:items"."fa1:price".text()`

Comment: Thanks for comment. Yes, quotes in notation work. But in my case works `records."fa1:price".text()`